# (cin >> int).get() doesn't properly work in Xcode(4.3.3)

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm currently working on the book "C++ Primer Plus" and doing some of the programming excersis.
As it seems, I'm having a problem with Xcode(4.3.3) because following code doesn't work how it's supposed to work:

```
  #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    struct car 
    {
        std::string maker;
        int year;
    };



int main() 
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << "How many cars do you wish to catalog? ";
    int nCars;
    (cin >> nCars).get();

    car* aCars = new car[nCars];

    for (int i = 0; i < nCars; i++) 
    {
        cout << "\nCar #" << (i + 1) << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the make: ";
        getline (cin, (aCars + i)->maker);
        cout << "\nPlease enter the year made: ";
        (cin >> (aCars + i)->year).get();
    }
    cout << "Here is your collection: \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < nCars; i++)
    {
        cout << (aCars + i)->year << " " << (aCars + i)->maker << endl;
    }

    delete [] aCars;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, I don't have the chance to enter any maker. The program directly goes to the point where I have to enter the year, even though I'm using "(cin >> nCars).get();" to get rid of the newline character.

Am I overlooking something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must never perform input operations without checking the return value. There's no point looking any further at this stage.

Comment: Use `std::vector<T>` in place of `new T[]`.

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have mentioned that the exersise in the book says the program should use "new" to create a dynamic array. The exerscise itself is very simple but I just don't know why the code above doesn't work properly.

Comment: `(cin >> nCars).get();` is trying to stuff multiple operations into one line for obfuscation. dont do that. make it two operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, guys..I found the problem.
The console within Xcode doesn't work as expected when using cin.get().
I tried the same code in the terminal as well as with Visual Studio (Win 7) and the program works perfectly.

Anyway, thank you all for your advices. I'll try consider them the next time. :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you may be running on windows and the two-byte newlines are hitting you. You may be able to improve things (for lines that aren't ridiculously long) with ignore:

```
cin >> nCars;
cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
```

Note that since you rely on stream numeric processing, entering a non-numeric year such as `QQ` will result in the programming just finishing without asking for any more input.

You don't need to do math on the years so treat them as strings instead of integers. Then if you need to you can do validation of each year after you get the input.

Comment: Seems unlikely. The C++ runtime for Windows "understands" newlines, and returns `'\n'` when it sees the two bytes in the input. Still, calling `ignore()` may patch over whatever the problem is.